# Is there a workaround in powerquery to refresh data when source file is open?

Tags: excel, powerquery, onedrive

[image: DataSourceError]

I have two Excel file save in OneDrive in different folder

Source.xlsx - source file

Dashboard.xlsx - extract data from source by power query

Note: Source file is shared by 2 users

I am looking for a workaround of how to fix such error as in image?

appreciated thank you in advance.

12Rev79

Comment: It's hard to understand your issue without more information or knowing what you've tried and what the result was.  Not sure if whether this is helpful:  https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/connect-data/refresh-data

Comment: I try to revised my question and attached an image of the error might help a little bit of clarity. Thanks again